# Live search using autocomplete node.js and express.js

Tags: node.js, ajax, mongodb, autocomplete

community. I am trying to implement a live search using the autocomplete library but every try is unsuccessful. I get every time a 500 server error. Every assistant is appreciated because I am new in coding. 
 I have a simple model for an article with title and body and I would like to show suggestions when the user search for an article

```js
model/article.js
// Method to construct the json result set
module.exports.buildResultSet=function(docs) {
    var result = [];
    for(var object in docs){
        result.push(docs[object]);
    }
    return result;
}
```

```js
routes/article.js

router.get('/search', function(req, res){
    encyclopediaModel.getMyArticlesByName(theRequester, function (pError, pFoundedArticles) {
        if (!pError) {
            // Method to construct the json result set
            var result = encyclopediaModel.buildResultSet(pFoundedArticles);
             res.json(result);
        } else {
           return res.json(JSON.stringify(pError), {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            }, 404);
        }


    },req.query.title)


});
```

```js
//Ajax call


 $("#search-query").autocomplete({
  source: function (request, response) {
   $.ajax({
    url: "/encyclopedia/search",
    type: "GET",
    data: request,  // request is the value of search input
    success: function (data) {
     response( data );
     console.log('success', data);
    }
   });
  },

  // The minimum number of characters a user must type before a search is performed.
  minLength: 3,

  // set an onFocus event to show the result on input field when result is focused
  focus: function (event, ui) {
   this.value = ui.item.label;
   // Prevent other event from not being execute
   event.preventDefault();
  },
  select: function (event, ui) {

  }
 });
```

```html
            <input id="search-query" type="text" placeholder="Articles...">
```

```
module.exports.getMyArticlesByName = function (requester, callback, pTitle){

    var regex = new RegExp(pTitle["term"], 'i');
    article.find({title: regex}, { 'title': 1 }).sort({"updated_at":-1}).sort({"created_at":-1}).limit(20).exec(callback);
}
```

Comment: can you share which data stored in your regex variable?? have your query return result or error?

Comment: @AnushkaAhir I am not sure what do you mean. In the regex, I store the title which is a string. Do you mean that?

Comment: var regex = new RegExp(pTitle["term"], 'i');   I want this variable value

Comment: Sorry but I am not sure about it and I cannot console.log because I am working on a virtual environment and the console.log does not work. Thanks for your assistant

Comment: @AnushkaAhir  using the winston.error i get this but I do not know if it is helpful .     {"message":"{\"ips\":\"/encyclopedia/search?term=Art\",\"query\":{\"term\":\"Art\"},\"date\":\"2019-08-02T08:47:11.941Z\"}","level":"error"}

Comment: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/regex/ this will help you

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197541/discussion-between-anushka-ahir-and-ioan-dimi).